# Build Process failed with maven package

Tags: linux, maven-2, build-process, centos

I am working on a maven project to build a simple utility api. The same source code when build on my office win XP machine, was successful. Now i am at home and working with same source code on CentOS machine. Here the build process failed strangely. The error it reports is ideally in my points should we warning message. As shown below.

```
[ERROR] com.vsd.Provider:[12,240] The import java.util.Set is never used
```

Can you please give me some idea, where can I look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the plug in being used to compile, It was a bug a shown below.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-118

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing your POM but the error reported looks like a violation of the Checkstyle rule [UnusedImports](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#UnusedImports) (or something equivalent). Maybe this verification is triggered because of a setting defined in a profile that is not activated on your CentOS machine (as I said, hard to say). Anyway, to fix it, remove the unused import.

Comment: Yes! I also thought of the case to have my codebase clean. But any way does this an error? why maven is reporting this. I have verified i am not using any plug in or any complex maven setting. Can you please give me a setting to do away this error.

Comment: @vijay.shad Maven doesn't report this as an error out of the box, you have something configured to do so (in your pom, in a profile of the pom, in a profile of your `~/.m2/settings.xml`, in a parent pom). But without seeing anything, the best advice I can give is: fix the problem, remove the unused import.

Comment: Here is my settings.xml file `http://pastebin.com/D0cPKyfw` and here is the pom.xml `http://pastebin.com/TYbwbmTS`. Please find the files.

Comment: @vijay.shad Hmm... there is *nothing* in the parts shown above that could explain the behavior but... I think that you removed some parts, maybe a parent pom (where is the property `${utils-webapp-version}` defined?).